# Get AVG() of CAST()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to calculate the average time a person is a member, before he/she becomes a paying member.

I'm trying to select the ID-Date of creation - Date of first payment - time between creation and first payment - Average of the time between creation and first payment:

```
SELECT C.CompanyId, C.CreatedDate, CO.CreatedDate,
CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int) AS 'Diff', FROM XXX.Company C
INNER JOIN -- some innerjoins--
WHERE -- Some conditions --
```

The first four selects works fine.

```
ID  Date of creation        Date of first payment   'Diff'
1   2013-12-29 00:00:00.000 2014-01-10 18:34:18.000   13
2   2013-12-09 00:00:00.000 2014-01-10 21:07:29.000   33
3   2013-12-12 00:00:00.000 2014-01-10 21:14:01.000   30
```

I would like to add AVG(Diff) AS Average to my select query

```
SELECT C.CompanyId, C.CreatedDate, CO.CreatedDate,
CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int) AS 'Diff', AVG(CAST(Diff as int)) AS Average FROM XXX.Company C
INNER JOIN -- some innerjoins--
WHERE -- Some conditions --
```

Which gives "invalid column name"

I tried to change it to

```
SELECT C.CompanyId, C.CreatedDate, CO.CreatedDate,CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int) AS 'Diff', AVG(CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int)) AS Average  FROM XXX.Company C
```

which gives the following error column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So basicly, how can I get the AVG() of a my CAST() as Diff?

SOLUTION

I used DATEDIFF http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

DATEDIFF(DAY,C.CreatedDate, CO.CreatedDate)
in order to remove the different datetime values, and get the difference
and used AVG around it:
AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, C.CreatedDate,CO.CreatedDate))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know how to mark my question as answered.
But I found the solution:

I used DATEDIFF http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

DATEDIFF(DAY,C.CreatedDate, CO.CreatedDate) in order to remove the different datetime values, and get the difference and used AVG around it: AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, C.CreatedDate,CO.CreatedDate))

mods, Please close this topic :)

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted one, by clicking on the tick next to your answer. Questions on SO aren't closed unless they are undesirable :-)

Comment: Thank you, I've to wait 1 hour more before I can close it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by some values to let the database know where the `avg` is applied to:

```
SELECT C.CompanyId
,      AVG(CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int)) AS Average
FROM   XXX.Company C
GROUP
BY     C.CompanyId
```

Also, you average and diff are conflicting, so you have to disable the cast then.

If you want all rows grouped on company and the two date created fields:

```
SELECT C.CompanyId
,      C.CreatedDate
,      CO.CreatedDate
,      CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int) AS 'Diff'
,      AVG(CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int)) AS Average
FROM   XXX.Company C
GROUP
BY     C.CompanyId
,      C.CreatedDate
,      CO.CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you would need to repeat the `CAST(...)` inside the `AVG()`, viz `CAST() as Diff, AVG(CAST(...)) as Average.`

You can avoid the repetition and DRY this up by wrapping the `CAST` query into an inner derived table, and then apply the `AVG` aggregate to this derived table, like so:

```
SELECT CompanyId, CreatedDate, CreatedDate, AVG(CAST(Diff as int)) AS Average 
FROM
(
   SELECT C.CompanyId, C.CreatedDate, CO.CreatedDate,
   CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int) AS 'Diff'
   FROM XXX.Company C
   INNER JOIN -- some innerjoins--
   WHERE -- Some conditions --
) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the average:

`SELECT AVG(CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int)) AS Average 
 FROM XXX.Company C ...`

If you want the average - say - per company:

`SELECT C.CompanyId, AVG(CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int)) AS Average 
 FROM XXX.Company C ... 
 GROUP BY C.CompanyId`

etc.

If you want to create a n-dimensional "cube" of data you can use group by grouping sets, group by rollup or group by cube as in:

`SELECT C.CompanyId, AVG(CAST(CO.CreatedDate - C.CreatedDate as int)) AS Average 
 FROM XXX.Company C ... 
 GROUP BY cube(C.CompanyId)`